# Copy specific file to emulator in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to copy a specific file(s) to **Emulator** in **Android**.
How it is possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if want push file to Emulator then you can use DDMS->select the emulator ->then open file explorer ->select SDcard->then click push button on right top to browse the file.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use adb. Here is the [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles).

And these are the specific commands (copy pasted from the previous link)

To copy a file or directory (recursively) from the emulator or device, use

```
adb pull <remote> <local>
```

To copy a file or directory (recursively) to the emulator or device, use

```
adb push <local> <remote>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the ddms perpective, there select your emulator if there are many and click the corresponding file explorer. There you can find the sdcard under mnt, and click the push a file symbol on the right side corner. It'll let you pick your file.

Answer (score 2):

**Using GUI:**

Android studio have new tool called `Device File Explorer`. You can access it in two way:

By clicking on `Device File Explorer` icon in right bottom corner of android studio window.
If you could not find its icon, inside Android Studio press shift button twice. Quick search window will appear, then type Device File in it and Device File Explorer will appear in search result and you can click it.

Then you can navigate to folder which you want to push your file in it. Right click on that folder and select upload(or press Ctrl+Shift+O). Select file you want to upload and it will upload file to desired location.

**Using terminal:**

You can use the ADB via a terminal to pass the file From Desktop to Emulator.

```
adb push <file-source-local> <file-destination-remote>
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of the Android emulator you can just drag the file into the emulator window. Then the file will be available to you in the Android file system.